# Crystal Reports 8.5 decimal values does not show

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem that my crystal report shows the decimal values as 00 every thing is fine but it does not display proper value 
e.g.

> If i have 0.235 it shows 0.000 If i have 2.356 it shows 2.000

Whats the matter behind it the database field is text based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this issue because your **rounding** is set to `1`.

- Right Click on field.
- Click on **Format Field**.
- Go to **Numbers Tab**.
- Click on **Customize**
- Under Number Tab **Change Rounding** To `0.001` or of you own desire.

Comment: its still not resolved now I am getting output 0.000

Comment: Maria Run your Sp or select records from your view or table, see what are values their. If they are same as you mentioned. Try to convert to string or text.

Comment: I database table all values are perfectly stored but in crystal reports the values after decimals showing zeros instead of their actual values

Comment: and this error is only showing in crystal reports 8.5 but in crystal reports 9 it works perfectly

Comment: Which BD you are using? you are getting result set from sp, view or table? and please check values in your result set you are using in your report not directly in table moreover are you making calculations on that field.

Comment: Run report on your production environment or in application, not in crystal report tool then check weather issue remains.

Comment: Also try verify Database.